# Getting different answers when computing $ \int \sin \theta \cos^3 \theta \, {\rm d}\theta $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$ \int \sin \theta \cos^3 \theta \, {\rm d}\theta $$

---

[image]

As you can see, I get a correct answer using the first approach and an incorrect answer using the second approach

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Are you sure the second solution is incorrect? Those two solutions may well be the same (up to a constant).

Comment: They are both correct. Their difference is a constant!

Comment: I MathJaxed a bit.  Please consider MathJaxing the photos

Answer (score 3):

Note that, for each $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
-\frac{\cos^4\theta}4-\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}2-\frac{\sin^4\theta}4\right)&=\frac14\left(\sin^4\theta-\cos^4\theta-2\sin^2\theta\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(\left(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta\right)\left(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\right)-2\sin^2\theta\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta-2\sin^2\theta\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(-\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta\right)\\
&=-\frac14,
\end{align}
and therefore your answers differ by a constant.

Comment: I understand now.  However, observe that $(\sin^2\theta - \cos^2\theta)(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta) - 2\sin^2\theta = \sin^2\theta - \cos^2\theta - 2\sin^2\theta = -\sin^2\theta - \cos^2\theta = -1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Indeed! Would you mind if I edit my answer, using that idea?

Comment: Go right ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are equivalent and both correct.

It is possible to end up with two distinct-looking answers to an integral. Suppose that you find $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are both indefinite integrals of $f(x)$. What this means is that:

- $F'=G'=f$
- Hence, by the mean value theorem, $F(x)=G(x)+k$ for some constant $k$

This is entirely fine. Remember, the goal of finding $\int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is simply to characterize all functions $F$ such that $F'=f$. From the second bullet point, if you have found one, you have found them all -- any antiderivative will differ from another by a constant.

You can see your answers are equivalent by the following:

- Graphing both of them, you see they're just a vertical shift apart:

[image]

- In fact, you should be able to set them equal to each other (with a constant $C$ on one side), and figure out the precise constant $C$ by which they differ.
- If you differentiate both of them, and manipulate trigonometric identities, you should be able to show that both of them have derivative $\sin(x) \cos^3(x)$.